# Como adaptar o href do JavaScript para acessar uma pagina com php?

Tags: php, javascript

Olá, estou tentando fazer com que o href do javascript traga o conteúdo de uma outra pagina em php para dentro de sua pagina de origem...

Bem não sei se consegui me explicar ao ponto dos amigos entenderem o que eu preciso...

Mas vamos lá...

Eu tenho esse código abaixo

```
    <ul id="songs-list">
    <li>
        <a class="song-link" href="javascript:;" title=""><strong>01</strong> Titulo 01 </a>
        <div class="single-song">
        <div class="song-links">
        <a class="close-btn" href="javascript:;" title="Voltar"></a>
            <div class="song-links-img">
                <img style="margin:-50px 0 0 -50px;" src="fancybox/img/escada.jpg" width="369" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1><strong>01</strong> Descrição do Produto 01 </h1>
        <div class="entry" style="overflow-y: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 100px;">
        <div class="jspContainer" style="width: 100px; height: 530px;">
        <div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100px;">
        </div></div></div>
        <span class="song-sides left-side"></span>
        <span class="song-sides right-side"></span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

que esta funcionando no endereço http://www.efacilfacil.com/#produtos.

Porém gostaria que esse href abaixo:

```
<a class="song-link" href="javascript:;" title=""></a>
```

Fosse adaptado com esse código abaixo:

```
<a href="prod_index_marca.php?codmarca=<?php echo $res['codigo'];?>"><?php echo $res['nome_marca'];?></a>
```

para que quando o usuario pesquisasse pela marca trouxesse todos os produtos relacionados a marca selecionada, conforme o endereço http://buziosnegocios.com.br/prod_index.php.

Não sei se consegui me expressar de forma que os amigos possam me ajudar.

Mas me coloco a disposição para esclarecer quaisquer duvida.

Abraços a todos, e desde já meus agradecimentos pela a atenção a minha duvida.

Comment: Precisas de ajuda a criar essa _query string_ no php ou a lêr no JavaScript?

Comment: Eu não entendi qual o evento. Os links irão aparecer na página como resultado de uma pesquisa? Vc vai usar AJAX ou vai carregar uma nova página?

Comment: Vamos lá, se você entrar nesse endereço http://buziosnegocios.com.br/prod_index.php, verá que quando o usuário seleciona uma determinada marca, retorna para ele todos os produtos referentes a quela marca selecionada em uma outra pagina de acordo com o cod. da marca selecionada, OK? Mas o que eu pretendo fazer e não tenho ideia de como, é criar um link tipo o desse endereço, http://www.efacilfacil.com/#produtos onde o usuário clica em Titulo 01 ou 02, e retorna para ele o resultado na mesma pagina, montando um href com os dois códigos de href mencionados no post. Pergunto aos amigos, tem como?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com a ajuda do amigo @Givanildo R. de Oliveira, conseguimos solucionar o problema e trazer somente os produtos referentes a Categoria selecionada.

Abaixo o código funcionando:

```
<?php include "conexao.php"; ?>

<div id="produtos" class="sections full-width-wrapper bg_4">
    <div class="centered-wrapper">

        <div class="section-header">
            <?php include 'menu_pags.php';?>            
        </div>

<div id="produtos-content">

    <!-- Listando os Categorias -->
    <?php
    $nome_cat = $_POST['nome_cat'];
    $img_cat = $_POST['img_cat'];
    $query_categoria = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categoria");
    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query_categoria)){
    ?>
    <div style="float:left; width:112px; height:133px; padding:2px 10px;" id="cats-list">
        <a class="cat-link" href="?nome_cat=<?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?>#produtos" title="<?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?>">
        <img style="position:relative; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);"
            src="img_cate/<?php echo $res['img_cat']; ?>" width="100"
            title="<?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?>" />
        </a>
        <div style="background:#2f2140; ; width:880px;z-index:999;border-radius:25px; <?php echo $res['nome_cat']==$_GET['nome_cat'] ? 'display:block;' : ''; ?>" class="single-cat">
            <h1 align="center" style="width:830px; margin-top:-40px;"><?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?></h1>
            <div style="margin-left:357px;width:50px;" class="cat-links">
                <a class="close-btn" href="javascript:;" title="Voltar">
                    <img src="img/fechar.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>

<!-- Listando os produtos -->
<?php
$nome_cat = $_GET['nome_cat'];
$query_produtos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE nome_cat = '$nome_cat'") or die(mysql_error());
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query_produtos)){

$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$img_prod = $_POST['img_prod'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
$nome_cat = $_POST['nome_cat'];
?>

    <div style="float:left; width:112px; height:133px; padding:2px 10px;" id="songs-list">
            <a class="song-link" href="javascript:;" title="">
            <img style="position:relative; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);" src="img_prod/<?php echo $res['img_prod']; ?>" width="100" title="<?php echo $res['titulo']; ?>" /></a>

        <div style=" margin-top:120px;z-index:999;border-bottom-right-radius:25px;border-top-right-radius:25px;" class="single-song">
            <div style="width:50px;margin-left:300px;" class="song-links">
            <a class="close-btn" href="javascript:;" title="Voltar">
                <img src="img/fechar.jpg" />
            </a>
                <div class="song-sides">
                    <img style="margin:40px 0 0 -142px;" src="img_prod/<?php echo $res['img_prod']; ?>" width="369" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />

            <h1> <?php echo $res['titulo']; ?> </h1>
            <div class="entry" style="overflow-y: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 100px;">
            <p style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#ccc;">
            <?php echo nl2br($res['descricao']); ?>
            </p>
            <div class="jspContainer" style="width: 100px; height: auto;">
            <div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100px;">
            </div></div></div>
            <span class="song-sides left-side"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>

</div></div></div>
```

Espero que possa ajudar a outros usuários com o mesmo problema.